# Continuously desktop region capture failed after some time - Unhandled exception in System.Drawing.dll (parameter is not valid)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, bitmap

I am making a an app where I have to capture selected desktop region continuously(using "Timer(CaptureTimer)" with interval 100) , resize it , make it to dither image & show it to "PictureBox(PreviewPictureBox)".
My app has two "Form"s.
One is "MainForm" contains "PreviewPictureBox" & "Button(StartButton)" & other is "CaptureForm" contains "CapturePictureBox".
"CaptureForm(size is 646x326)" is transparent & FromBorderStyle = none.
"CapturePictureBox" is "dock in parent container" & has a side bordered & middle transparent png picture in it.
"CaptureForm" can be move by click & dragging the "CapturePictureBox".

This is "MainForm"

[image]

Here is "MainForm" Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _128x64_GLCD_Monitor
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    CaptureForm CapF = new CaptureForm();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public Bitmap ScreenCaptureBitmap(int DesktopX, int DesktopY, int CaptureWidth, int CaptureHeight)
    {
        Bitmap ScreenCaptureBmp = new Bitmap(CaptureWidth, CaptureHeight);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(ScreenCaptureBmp as Image);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(DesktopX, DesktopY, 0, 0, ScreenCaptureBmp.Size);
        return ScreenCaptureBmp;
    }

    public Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap ResizeBmp, int RBmpWidth, int RBmpHeight)
    {
        Bitmap RBmp = new Bitmap(RBmpWidth, RBmpHeight);
        using (Graphics RBmpG = Graphics.FromImage((Image)RBmp))
            RBmpG.DrawImage(ResizeBmp, 0, 0, RBmpWidth, RBmpHeight);
        return RBmp;
    }   

    public Bitmap DitherBitmap(Bitmap DitherBmp) // Not writing full method here

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CapF.Show();
        CaptureTimer.Start();
    }

    private void CaptureTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int windowLeft = CapF.Left + 3;
        int windowTop = CapF.Top + 3;
        int windowWidth = CapF.Width - 6;
        int windowHeight = CapF.Height - 6;

        Bitmap Pic = ScreenCaptureBitmap(windowLeft, windowTop, windowWidth, windowHeight);
        Bitmap Pic1 = ResizeBitmap(Pic, 128, 64);
        Bitmap Pic2 = DitherBitmap(Pic1);
        PreviewPictureBox.Image = Pic2;
    }

}
}
```

This is "CaptureForm"

[image]

Here is "CaptureForm" Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _128x64_GLCD_Monitor
{
public partial class CaptureForm : Form
{
    Boolean TogMove;
    int MValX, MValY;

    public CaptureForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CaptureForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TransparencyKey = BackColor;
    }

    private void CapturePictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TogMove = true;
        MValX = e.X;
        MValY = e.Y;
    }

    private void CapturePictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TogMove == true)
        {
            this.SetDesktopLocation(MousePosition.X - MValX, MousePosition.Y - MValY);
        }
    }

    private void CapturePictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TogMove = false;
    }

}
}
```

When I start debugging, after some time(after completing some loop) it getting this message

[image]

Visual Studio 2010 pointed this line(at a 1 time debugging 1 line)

Some time this line

```
Bitmap ScreenCaptureBmp = new Bitmap(CaptureWidth, CaptureHeight);
```

Or some time this line

```
graphics.CopyFromScreen(DesktopX, DesktopY, 0, 0, ScreenCaptureBmp.Size);
```

From this method

```
public Bitmap ScreenCaptureBitmap(int DesktopX, int DesktopY, int CaptureWidth, int CaptureHeight)
```

What I have to do to prevent this error?

Comment: It is the kind of exception you get when your program runs out of available unmanaged memory.  Which is unsurprising, you have several places in your code where you forget to dispose objects.  Most bugs are located in the CaptureTimer_Tick() method, you forget to dispose the old PreviewPictureBox.Image, Pic and Pic1.

Comment: Why I can't Dispose Pic1 & Pic2 after use?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following 4 variables are within the size of the Form.  When you click the numbers can be negative or greater than the size (width , height) of the form. :

```
       int windowLeft = CapF.Left + 3;
        int windowTop = CapF.Top + 3;
        int windowWidth = CapF.Width - 6;
        int windowHeight = CapF.Height - 6;
```

Comment: Why you said about the following 4 variables may not be in "CaptureForm" size?

Does "4 variables must be in "CaptureForm" size" really too much matter?
I just use it to get a desktop location.
I can't see logical error in it. Tell me if I am wrong...

Though I am not resizing "CaptureForm" & not moving it, it also crash...

Comment: Why make a comment unless you do a simple test to verify if I'm right or wrong?  You posted 34 different errors and the common error indicates the one or more of the 4 properties are wrong.   Initially during the form load event often properties like the 4 items are -1 (or zero) until form is fully loaded  but events are enabled so first event must be ignored.

Comment: You are understanding me wrong. I am not arguing , I am wondering & don't know the answer that's why asking...
I understand about 4 items & why first event must be ignored. But my app does not crash in first event, "CaptureForm" just serve it's purpose for many complete loop(in "CaptureTimer"). So I am thinking if the second loop works perfectly then those 4 items should contain right data.
If I just set the values in those 4 items, it also crash on line

"graphics.CopyFromScreen(DesktopX, DesktopY, 0, 0, ScreenCaptureBmp.Size);"

 You said 34 different errors. Please tell if possible.

Comment: The code may be failing depending on location of mouse.  Simply add : if((CapF.Left <= 0) || (CapF.Top <= 0) || (CapF.Width <= 0) || (CapF.Height <= 0) || (windowWidth <= 0) || (windowHeight <= 0)) return;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the values for windowLeft, WindowTop, windowWidth or windowHeight in your timer methode, went negative.
If you only want to prevent this error, you can simply set the values in an if-clause before you call the method ScreenCaptureBitmap(...) or you prevent the dragging to negative values in the LocationChanges-Event.

Comment: If I just set the values in those 4 items, it also crash on line

"graphics.CopyFromScreen(DesktopX, DesktopY, 0, 0, ScreenCaptureBmp.Size);".

But setting fixed value causes crash in later(may be after 20 min). But it is still not bugless...